# Hard fault in STM32F101RF due to MRC2 Disassembly?

Tags: arm, cortex-m, iar

I am having a bootloader code wherein I will sending/receiving data via USART . I have configured USART to operate in interrupt mode.

USART functionality works perfectly fine independently. Verified this with multiple read/write instances.

When I integrate USART code with my bootloader code, bootloader will keep on checking if there is any pending data to read from USART.

If there is any pending data, bootloader will read the Data Register (DR) for the data received already through interrupt. (kind of polling + interrupt)

My problem :

Whenever there is an USART receive interrupt is triggered , inside receive interrupt service routine hard fault error occurs.

PC says its inside hard fault routine where I read data from DR.

But a strange thing I saw is, from the location where hard fault hits, in the disassembly I see only MRC2 commands[image]

Is the issue occuring because of this ?? 0x8004802 is the location where my hardfault hits.

Kindly enlighten me on this

Comment: compile the code to assembly see what it looks like.  are you using the debugger to disassemble or the toolchains disassembler?  disassemble the binary compare to what you see when you dump the flash for that address space.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the raw hex values: 0xFF all the way starting with a suspicious address `0x8004800` which is for sure a page boundary.

In other words: The flash memory is bad or was erased and not completely written. Verifying the flashed program (bootloader) should fail.

If that was in your bootloader code, it might have tried to overwrite itself - or simply erased the wrong memory page.